# TinyMCE: Set background-color for complete editor content?

Tags: css, tinymce, tinymce-4

I'm using TinyMCE 4. Unfortunately the "backcolor" control seems to only allow changes to text, not a whole paragraph. Even when I select a paragraph in the status bar of TinyMCE and apply a background color, it's only applied to the inner span, not the paragraph itself. I would need to set the background color for the complete content, not only parts of it. This should be applied to the HTML output, something like

```
<div style="background-color: #f00">[complete editor content]</div>
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this code to access the tinymce's body to set background color:

```
tinymce.activeEditor.getBody().style.backgroundColor = '#<yourcolor>';
```

Disadvantage: Setting the background color that way will not change/affect the html content inside the editor. So you have to treat/update/store that value in a separate way.

You can also add a button on initialising tinymce:

```
tinymce.init({
...
        setup: function (editor) {
            editor.addButton('mybutton', {
                text: 'Set bgColor',
                icon: false,
                onclick: function () {
                    editor.getBody().style.backgroundColor = '#E5FFCC';
                }
            });
...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to reach the editable content body in the dynamically generated iframe. The iframe is generated after the initialization of the editor.

If your textarea id is foo, the id of the iframe is foo_ifr.

You may also open the editor with firebug or developer tools and use dom explorer, you may see the inner dynamically generated components.

use:

```
var iframe = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0];
// or
var iframe = document.getElementsById("foo_ifr");

// check if iframe.contentDocument is cross-browser, i tested with IE 11.
var innerBody = iframe.contentDocument.getElementsByClassName("mceContentBody")[0];
innerBody.style.backgroundColor="red";
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm afraid setting the style for the body won't have an impact on the html fragment that is posted back. I would need to cycle over all block elements in the iframe body and add background-color or wrap the content in a div with bg-color running into danger that these styles get overwritten again by TinyMCE if the user makes further changes in the editor. Besides that "hacking" solution I was hoping for some TinyMCE control or build-in function to set bg-color for all the content.

Answer (score 0):

To get the custom styling that you want, you have to create new custom style formats when the editor is being initialized. This gives you the ability to define css styling to the element. For example

HTML

```
<form>
    <textarea></textarea>
</form>
```

JS

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: 'textarea',
    //merge with default formats
    style_formats_merge: true,
    //set up custom style formats 
    style_formats: [
        {title: 'Red Background', block: 'p', styles: {
            'background-color': '#ff0000', 
            'color':'white',
            'padding': '7px'}
        },
        {title: 'Blue Background', block: 'p', styles: {
            'background-color': '#0000ff', 
            'color':'white',
            'padding': '7px'}
        }
    ]
});
```

This merges two new custom formats with the default formats. See this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/PalinDrome555/symgbbyL/1/)

Comment: Thank you, this comes very close to what I need. But is there a way to assign the bg-color to the complete content and not just single <p>-blocks? So that I get something like <div style="background-color:red">[complete tinyMCE editor HTML output]</div>?

Comment: Ah I misinterpreted your question. AFAIK there is no built in functionality for this, you can always build your own function. Another thing do you want this to display in the editor, or when you retrieve the content from the editor?

Comment: Actually both so I do not break the wysiwyg format of the editor. I will need to build a custom function anyway which adds special HTML blocks with product information, so maybe I solve that background issue by the way). Quite a challenge - the tinyMCE documentation is more than confusing. It took me a while to realize that the docs for v4 often refer to v3 functions that are not yet implemented (e.g. the tinyMCEPopup script which provides communication between popups and editor is not available in the v4 download).

Comment: I agree, the documentation is confusing for most of it!